# Testing a custom RepositoryRestController that uses a PersistentEntityResourceAssembler

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-test, spring-rest

I have a `RepositoryRestController` that exposes resources for some persistent entities.

I have a method on my controller that takes a `PersistentEntityResourceAssembler` to help me generate the resources automatically.

```
@RepositoryRestController
@ExposesResourceFor(Customer.class)
@RequestMapping("/api/customers")
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService service;

    @RequestMapping(method = GET, value="current")
    public ResponseEntity getCurrent(Principal principal Long id, PersistentEntityResourceAssembler assembler) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(assembler.toResource(service.getForPrincipal(principal)));
    }
}
```

(Contrived example, but it saves going into too much detail about irrelevant details of my use-case)

I'd like to write a test for my controller (my real use-case is actually worth testing), and am planning on making use of @WebMvcTest.

So I have the following test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(CustomerController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure=false)
public class CustomerControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc client;

    @MockBean
    private CustomerService service;

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        // test stuff in here
    }

    @Configuration
    @Import(CustomerController.class)
    static class Config {
    }

}
```

But I get an exception saying `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.<init>()`

Presumably something is not being configured correctly here because I'm missing the entire data layer.  Is there some way of mocking out the `PersistentEntityResourceAssembler`?  Or another approach I could use here?

Comment: What happens if you make the `CustomerController` class public?

Comment: Sorry, that was a C&P mistake, and not related to this problem (nice catch though!).  The problem here is that spring sees it needs to pass a PERA through, but doesn't have one.  The problem is almost certainly with my test configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up for now with:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
```

The downsite of it is that the test would start the full Spring application context (but without the server).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing a slightly hacky solution here:

- I removed `PersistentEntityResourceAssembler` from the controller method.
- I added an `@Autowired RepositoryEntityLinks` to the controller, on which I call `linkToSingleResource` to create the links as needed.
- I added an `@MockBean RepositoryEntityLinks` to my test class, and configured the mocking to return something sensible:

  ```
  given(repositoryEntityLinks.linkToSingleResource(any(Identifiable.class)))
          .willAnswer(invocation -> {
              final Identifiable identifiable = (Identifiable) invocation.getArguments()[0];
              return new Link("/data/entity/" + identifiable.getId().toString());
          });
  ```

It's far from ideal - I'd love to know if there's a way of getting just enough of the data layer up that I can depend on `PersistentEntityResourceAssembler`.